# How to access class variables from module?

Tags: ruby

I was wondering how can I access class variables from modules

```
module Entity
  def foo
    # puts @@rules
  end
end

class Person
  include Entity

  attr_accessor :id, :name

  @@rules = [[:id, :int, :not_null],
             [:name, :string, :not_null]]
end

class Car
  include Entity

  attr_accessor :id, :year

  @@rules = [[:id, :string, :not_null],
             [:year:, :int, :not_null]]
end

p = Person.new
c = Car.new

p.foo # [[:id, :int, :not_null], [:name, :string, :not_null]]
c.foo # [[:id, :string, :not_null], [:year, :int, :not_null]]
```

I took a look at `cattr_accessor` and `mattr_accessor` from `ActiveSupport`, but still can't find a way to solve this.

Answer (score 12):

Class variables in Ruby are weird when it comes to inheritance. Unless you know exactly what you're messing with there, it's best to avoid them. You might think you aren't using inheritance in this case, but what `include` actually does is inserts `Entity` into the ancestors of `Person`. See:

```
Person.ancestors
# [Person, Entity, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

The particular behavior is tricky to describe, but the short version is that basically `@@rules` is shared between `Entity`, `Person`, *and* `Car`! Look:

```
Entity.class_variable_set(:@@rules, 'foo')
puts Car.class_variable_get(:@@rules)
# foo
puts Person.class_variable_get(:@@rules)
# foo
```

You probably don't want that!

It's better to use a class *instance* variable here, which is actually separate for each class.

```
module Entity 
  # create the class instance variable methods when this is included
  def self.included klass
    klass.singleton_class.send(:attr_reader, :rules)
  end

  def foo
    puts self.class.rules
  end
end

class Person
  include Entity

  attr_accessor :id, :name

  @rules = [[:id, :int, :not_null],
            [:name, :string, :not_null]]
end

class Car
  include Entity

  attr_accessor :id, :year

  @rules = [[:id, :string, :not_null],
            [:year, :int, :not_null]]
end
```

Comment: I like this answer, but in this case, the attribute `rules` is being exposed

Comment: You can just as easily make it a reader rather than an accessor, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: It is still being exposed (anyway, using reflection as the first answer does,  it can be accessed too)

Answer (score 2):

It's not the most elegant solution but [class_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) works:

```
module Entity
  def foo
    self.class.class_eval('@@rules')
  end
end
```

Edit: Actually slightly cleaner may be to use [class_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-class_variable_get)

```
module Entity
  def foo
    self.class.class_variable_get(:@@rules)
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, ty! The code works and that's great! I hope an answer in which the code would be more elegant!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the already given answers, here's something I found out sometime back.

```
module MyModule
  @@my_variable = 5
  define_singleton_method(:my_variable) do
    @@my_variable
  end
end
```

Now you'll be able to access the class variable in two ways:
`MyModule::my_variable` or `MyModule.my_variable`.

This now works like an attr_reader. You can define a second singleton method for assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really my answer, it's a variation on @Max's answer, just without exposing the `@rules` variable (see @Quarktum's comments).

The difference here is that I'm using the [`#module_exec` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-module_exec), which allows instance variable access (unlike `#module_eval`).

Also, I'm defining the `.foo` and `#foo` methods under the scope of the including class, so that the methods are the classes methods rather than the module's methods (test with `Car.methods false` to view Car's methods without inheritance).

```
module Entity 
  # create the class instance variable methods when this is included
  def self.included klass
    klass.module_exec do
      @rules ||= []
      def self.foo
        puts @rules
      end
      def foo
        self.class.foo
      end
    end
  end
end

class Person
  include Entity

  attr_accessor :id, :name

  @rules = [[:id, :int, :not_null],
                [:name, :string, :not_null]]
end

class Car
  include Entity

  attr_accessor :id, :year

  @rules = [[:id, :string, :not_null],
                [:year, :int, :not_null]]
end
```