# Ruby - uninitialized class variable in instance methods

Tags: ruby, mixins, instance-variables, class-variables

I'm working on RoR course and I receive an error in irb console:
"NameError: uninitialized class variable @@instances in InstanceCounter::InstanceMethods"

What I need to change in my modules.rb?

Console:

```
Evgenys-MacBook-Pro-2:lesson_05 admin$ irb
2.3.1 :001 > load 'modules.rb'
 => true 
2.3.1 :002 > load 'car.rb'
 => true 
2.3.1 :003 > car=Car.new
initialize
NameError: uninitialized class variable @@instances in InstanceCounter::InstanceMethods
Did you mean?  instance_methods
from modules.rb:35:in `initialize'
from (irb):3:in `new'
from (irb):3
from /Users/aku/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

modules.rb:

```
module InstanceCounter
  module ClassMethods

    @@instances = 0

    def instances
      puts "@@instances"
      @@instances
    end

  end

  module InstanceMethods

    def initialize
      puts "initialize"
      register_instance
      super
    end

    protected

    def register_instance
      @@instances += 1
      puts "@@instances += 1"
    end

  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.send :prepend, InstanceMethods
  end
end
```

car.rb:

```
class Car
  include InstanceCounter

  def initialize
    puts "initialize2"
  end  
end

class PassengerCar < Car
end

class CargoCar < Car
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the class variable in the InstanceMethods module. It looks like extend only adds methods to the calling object by default.

Documentation on default ruby implementations for reference: [extend](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-extend) and [include](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-append_features)

Comment: `extend` doesn't "add" anything. `o.extend(M)` simply makes `M` the superclass of the singleton class of `o`. IOW, it's (more or less) equivalent to `class << o; include M end` (`include` makes the module the superclass of the class).

Comment: "Put the class variable in the InstanceMethods module" - not working((( I've added @@instances = 0 to ClassMethods and InstanceMethods - it doesn't work correctly. If I add @@instances = 0 to InstanceMethods only - I receive an error in irb: Car.instances ->>> "NameError: uninitialized class variable @@instances in InstanceCounter::ClassMethods"

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Jörg. @EvggenyS I didn't give a great answer to your question, and ruby inheritance can be a bit confusing. I think this question might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022273/how-to-access-class-variables-from-module